# Connecting a single 8 Ohm speaker to 4 Ohm stereo output

Tags: amplifier, speakers

I have an amplifier that has stereo outputs for two 4 Ohm speakers. Now I want to connect a single 8 Ohm speaker to it. How should I go about this? Can I simply unite the two stereo cables and connect them to the single speaker? Or is this more complicated?

Comment: You can't connect two amplifier outputs to a single speaker. Use one output for one speaker.

Answer (score 0):

You might add 8 Ω resistors in series with each output high-side, **if they share a common ground**, and connect the resistors to the speaker. This would provide some isolation between the output amplifiers.

However, the output would see ~16 Ω to ground, rather than 4 Ω. Some amplifiers are fine with that, others would require a 4.7 Ω resistor directly across each output to reduce distortion.

However, if the amplifier has *floating* ground, connecting the grounds together could destroy it.

Answer (score 0):

With the lack of information provides such as make,model, power,etc there is only one way that I feel would be safe to do this. I would to put a 4 Ohm resistor on the unused right channel. Then parallel the 8 Ohm speaker with an 8 Ohm resistor on the left channel. Be sure the resistors can handle the wattage. Select mono if you can, to keep it relative clean and set the balance all the way to the left. Years ago the left channel was the prefered mono channel, with your equipment I have no idea.